# R: using ranger with caret, tuneGrid argument

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret

I'm using the [caret](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) package to analyse Random Forest models built using [ranger](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ranger/index.html). I can't figure out how to call the train function using the tuneGrid argument to tune the model parameters.

I think I'm calling the tuneGrid argument wrong, but can't figure out why it's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
data(iris)

library(ranger)
model_ranger <- ranger(Species ~ ., data = iris, num.trees = 500, mtry = 4,
                       importance = 'impurity')


library(caret)

# my tuneGrid object:
tgrid <- expand.grid(
  num.trees = c(200, 500, 1000),
  mtry = 2:4
)

model_caret <- train(Species  ~ ., data = iris,
                     method = "ranger",
                     trControl = trainControl(method="cv", number = 5, verboseIter = T, classProbs = T),
                     tuneGrid = tgrid,
                     importance = 'impurity'
)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is the syntax for ranger in caret:

```
library(caret)
```

add `.` prior to tuning parameters:

```
tgrid <- expand.grid(
  .mtry = 2:4,
  .splitrule = "gini",
  .min.node.size = c(10, 20)
)
```

Only these three are supported by caret and not the number of trees. In train you can specify num.trees and importance:

```
model_caret <- train(Species  ~ ., data = iris,
                     method = "ranger",
                     trControl = trainControl(method="cv", number = 5, verboseIter = T, classProbs = T),
                     tuneGrid = tgrid,
                     num.trees = 100,
                     importance = "permutation")
```

to get variable importance:

```
varImp(model_caret)

#output
             Overall
Petal.Length 100.0000
Petal.Width   84.4298
Sepal.Length   0.9855
Sepal.Width    0.0000
```

To check if this works set number of trees to 1000+ - the fit will be much slower. After changing `importance = "impurity"`:

```
#output:

             Overall
Petal.Length  100.00
Petal.Width    81.67
Sepal.Length   16.19
Sepal.Width     0.00
```

If it does not work I recommend installing latest ranger from CRAN and caret from git hub:

```
devtools::install_github('topepo/caret/pkg/caret')
```

To train the number of trees you can use `lapply` with fixed folds created by `createMultiFolds` or `createFolds`.

**EDIT**: while the above example works with caret package version 6.0-84, using the names of hyper parameters without dots works as well.

```
tgrid <- expand.grid(
  mtry = 2:4,
  splitrule = "gini",
  min.node.size = c(10, 20)
)
```

Comment: Why do you need to ad the dot prior to turning parameters?

Comment: @dule arnaux This is just how the creator of `caret` defined them.

Comment: @missuse caret documentation doesn't have the dots in the tuning parameters it describes https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html. And for other models i've run without the dots. So wondering if this is some older legacy way of doing it?

Comment: @dule arnaux Quite possibly my answer is deprecated. I will check and update the answer .